# Product weight in shopify admin differs from what is returned in api

Tags: shopify

I have a situation where my users are providing their product weights in pounds, kilograms but it's returned in the api as grams. I tried to solve this by writing my own weight conversion functions but users felt it wasn't accurate to what they put on shopify. Is there a way for shopify to return what is exactly put in the admin by users or provide the the rate at which they are converting weights from lbs to grams or kgs to gms. Hope it makes sense. If there is any documentation on this, i will be willing to take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

See this page on the Shopify wiki for more info on how a product's weight is stored: [How much precision does Shopify use to store my products' weight?](http://docs.shopify.com/support/your-store/products/how-much-precision-does-shopify-use-to-store-my-products-weight)

It states:

> All weights are stored in grams in Shopify. The weights are rounded to the nearest whole number (nearest gram).
>   ...
>   For more precision over weights you may choose to use the Metric System. Using Grams for product weights will allow you to set the product weight explicitly.

You can format the weight using the [weight_with_unit](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-basics/5-output#weight_with_unit) liquid filter. For example:

```
{% for variant in product.variants %}
  {{ variant.weight | weight_with_unit }}
{% endfor %}
```